# Limit of queries in a fql Multiquery at once

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to find out what is the limit of queries in one fql multiquery on Facebook, but I'm unable to find any answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation of facebook says that is 50.